# Linq joins on three tables

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, reporting-services

I have three tables Terminals, CompaignTerminal(Bridge Table), Compaign I want to select all terminals but also those compaings who are associative with any terminal Terminal has Terminalid and Title Compaign also CompaignId and Title and CompaignTerminal has both forigern keys[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FIwoo.png)

Comment: I'm afraid I'm finding it very hard to understand the question. It would be much easier to help you with sample data, and ideally a [mcve] showing what you've got so far.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! This is a Q&A site not a "please do it for me site". Show us what you tried.

Comment: just see the image that attached with it

Comment: from t in _dbContext.Terminals join ct in_dbContext.CompaignTerminals on t.TerminalId equals ct.TerminalId into ter   from x in ter.DefaultIfEmpty   join com in _dbContext.Compaigns on x.CompaignId equals com.CompaignId
     select new CompaignTerminalDTO
                                        {
  checkbox=false, compaignid=com.CompaignId, compaigntitle = com == null ? "Not Assscoated" : com.Title,
 terminalid = t.TerminalId,
                                            terminaltitle =t.Identifier 
                                        }).ToList();